# Storing and collecting data

Tags: python, sql

I wanted to ask you which coding language I should use. I am pretty new to coding and could really use some help.

As I mentioned above I want to **create a survey and afterward store my results in a database**.

**Details**:

The survey should be available for a longer period of time (a few years) and the results should be transferred daily to the database.

The survey starts with a general identification (name, age, gender, etc.).
An ID is then assigned to the participants (in case they want to add more answers to the survey AFTER they have completed it).

Afterward, the identification of the actual survey takes place. In this part, I would like to query recurring events. For example, classes attended at the university with subcategories (date, GPA, etc.) **Each candidate has attended 1 to x classes.**

Here is my first problem, **how can I achieve that every candidate can enter all his classes?**

For example, is there the following possibility that I ask the following question after each class: Have you attended any other classes? If "NO", the survey is declared closed, if "YES", he can enter another class.

**The next problem**, I have is that I want to make sure that different people name the same class the same way. So I want to have the possibility that as soon as you are participant 2, you get the already entered classes of participant 1 as a suggestion.

Then I would like to transfer the information into a database. (if possible with MySQL).
And if possible I also would like to visualize it.

I just wanted to ask you which coding language you would recommend.

So far I have little coding experience with Python and Java.

Answer (score 0):

There are several separate issues:

1. Survey design
2. Collection
3. Data querying
4. Visualization

Each issue has its own best practices for solutions.

Generally, survey design and collection are independent of coding language. Data querying from a database is done with SQL. Visualization can be done with or without a coding language.

Python and Java can help to automate the process.